# Can I convert jam into chutney?

Tags: jam, chutney

I made a rhubarb jam a little while ago, basically rhubarb, sugar and grated ginger.  Its quite gingery.

I've now made some duck terrine and fancy serving it with some chutney.  I have some chutney, but I wouldn't mind trying to convert some of my rhubarb jam into a rhubarb chutney, to use tonight.

Not really sure how I might go about this, but was thinking I might soften some onions and garlic, then mix these and some cider vinegar into some of the jam.

Is this likely to work?  Anyone got any better ideas?  Would it be different if I had more time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perfect idea and great multi-use of your jam!  Your plan is perfect...just create a nice sweet tart balance to your liking.  If you want a little more texture you could plump up some golden or dark raisins by nuking them in the microwave before adding.  Coriander seed is often used and provides a little texture contrast as well.  A bit of ground allspice could be good as well.

Comment: Just to say, I went with ground allspice and some roughly ground caraway seeds and it worked a treat.  Thanks again.

Comment: Great!  Glad you liked it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same dilemma. Last year I used the plums from my plum tree to make a lot of plum jam and (as an afterthought) only one jar of plum chutney. Most of the jam went into the freezer. I ate one jar of it but I don't eat jam much so the remaining jam has been sitting in the freezer for nearly a year! However the chutney went VERY quickly as I like it with curry. So, today, I took the remaining plum jam from the freezer, defrosted it and put it into a big pot. In a separate pan I fried 4 chopped/diced onions, a couple chopped/diced carrots, some garlic, some ginger, and threw in various herbs that I found in the cupboards and let it cook for a while, then added about 400ml of white-wine vinegar and 400ml of red-wine vinegar and then combined it with the now bubbling jam, stirred it for a bit and then let it cool. I now have 4 good-sized jars of tasty plum chutney. Yummy!

Answer (score 2):

I like all Darin's suggestions, but my contribution (late, as usual) is to suggest using apple or banana to mix with the jam.

Core out and chop an apple, microwave it for a minute or two, and you have the perfect "tart balance" material to mix with that jam. If you're feeling lazy, you will find you can separate the flesh from the peel with a spoon after microwaving. Stick with the allspice and coriander - my two favorite spices.

Banana will also work in the same way, but you get less texture.